# How to fix my title slide (problem with aligning text)

Tags: beamer, spacing, titles, frame-title

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
 \usetheme{Rochester}

 \title{my title which is very long so pushes the date off the page}
 \author[Author]{my name}
 \institute[university ]{\normalsize university
 University of \\[\baselineskip]
 \[ 
 \begin{tabular}[T]{l@{}l}
 $\text{Supervisors }$ : \mbox{} & supervisor 1 \\
                    & supervisor 2 with a different length name but I still    want things aligned
 \end{tabular}
 \]
 }


  \begin{document}
  \frame{\titlepage}


  \end{document}
```

Hello, I printed my code above as I think it's easier to show what i'm trying to do in code rather than with words.

Basically, I just want a normal looking title page where I nearly list my supervisors in an aligned fashion, given that they have different length names this is difficult. I used the tabular solution but it doesn't quite work because it leaves a large blank space and pushes the date down so it's invisible.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you were entering displayed math to typeset the table of supervisors, but doing so adds extra space above and below which meant there was too much content for the slide.

Just don't use displayed math (or any math, for that matter) here. You can also avoid the awkward `\mbox` construct in the table by adding the space in the inter-column insert: `@{ }` (with space) instead of `@{}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}

\title{my title which is very long so pushes the date off the page}
\author[Author]{my name}
\institute[university ]{
  \normalsize university
  University of \\[\baselineskip]
  \begin{tabular}{l@{ }l}
    Supervisors : & supervisor 1 \\
                  & supervisor 2 with a different length name
  \end{tabular}
}


\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]